# SQL query to join tables with duplicate rows and getting unique rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-bigquery-java

I got the following three tables  in BigQuery along with the data below.

I'd like to write a SQL query using id and current date columns and get the following row as the output.

Expected result set:

```
id            existing_stores                             missing_stores
1003812607    "3640,0130,0131,2306,3638,0127,2789,2305"   "3102,2681,2686,2670,2682,3101,2673,2669,3103,2668"
```

These are the tables:

`item` table:

```
id            date
------------------------
1003812607    2023-08-03
1003812607    2023-08-01
1003812607    2023-07-23
1003812607    2023-06-30
```

`item_change_history`:

```
createdTime                     docType    id       existing_stores
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-08-03 11:01:10.139617 UTC  Item    1003812607  "3640,0130,0131,2306,3638,0127,2789,2305"
2023-07-01 09:01:10.139617 UTC  Item    1003812607  "3640,0130,0131,2306,3638,0127,2789,2301"
```

`mic_item_discrepancy`:

```
ID          MISSING_STORE
-------------------------
1003812607  3102
1003812607  2681
1003812607  2686
1003812607  2670
1003812607  2682
1003812607  3101
1003812607  2673
1003812607  2669
1003812607  3103
1003812607  2668
```

I tried to come up with this query and it is not working as expected or giving me the wrong data given that duplicate id rows in
`mic_item_discrepancy` table.

```
SELECT 
    item.id, ich.id, ich.existing_stores, mid.missing_stores
FROM 
    `hd-merch-prod.merch_item_cache_validation.item` item 
JOIN
    `hd-merch-prod.merch_item_cache.item_change_history` ich 
         ON item.date = "2023-08-03" 
         AND DATE(ich.createdTime) = item.date 
         AND ich.id = item.id  
JOIN
    `hd-merch-prod.merch_item_cache.mic_item_discrepancy` mid 
         ON item.id = mid.id
GROUP BY
    item.id, ich.id, ich.existing_stores, mid.missing_stores;
```

Comment: Hi @gcpdev-guy, did the answer below help you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `LEFT JOIN` for both the `item_change_history` and `mic_item_discrepancy` tables to ensure that all rows from the item table are included in the result, and add a `DISTINCT` in the `STRING_AGG` function:

```
SELECT 
    item.id, ich.id, ich.existing_stores, COALESCE(mid.missing_stores, '') AS missing_stores
FROM 
    `hd-merch-prod.merch_item_cache_validation.item` item 
LEFT JOIN
    (
      SELECT id, existing_stores, MAX(createdTime) as latest_createdTime
      FROM 
        `hd-merch-prod.merch_item_cache.item_change_history`
      WHERE 
        DATE(createdTime) = '2023-08-03'
      GROUP BY 
        id, existing_stores
    ) ich ON item.id = ich.id  
LEFT JOIN
    (
      SELECT ID, STRING_AGG(DISTINCT MISSING_STORE, ',') AS missing_stores 
      FROM 
        `hd-merch-prod.merch_item_cache.mic_item_discrepancy`
      GROUP BY 
        ID
    ) mid ON item.id = mid.ID;
```